# creating pie graph with laravel with json response

Tags: laravel

i want to know how to get laravel javascript query for my chart
why does it always return the data without making a pie chart, always to the json view

code in view:

```
<script>
  // get data from database using Ajax or fetch
  fetch('/api/data')
    .then(response => {
        let data = response.data;

        let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

code in controller:

```
$data = DB::table('suara')
    ->groupBy('suara')
    ->pluck(DB::raw('sum(jml_suara) as sum'), 'suara')
    ->toarray();

    // format data for pie chart
    $labels = [];
    $values = [];
    foreach ($data as $item => $key) {
        $labels[] = $item;
        $values[] = $key;
    }return response()->json([
        'labels' => $labels,
        'datasets' => [
            [
                'data' => $values,
                'backgroundColor' => ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56', '#F44336']
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: what chart library are you using?

Comment: maybe I haven't included it.I missed it

Comment: Oh, cool include and see if that fix the problem

Comment: I immediately tried. thanks for the reminder

Comment: already installed, but I'm still confused about how to run the data to javascript,

Comment: `let data = response.data;` ===>>> `console.log(data)`, because this is what you're getting from the backend: `[
        'labels' => $labels,
        'datasets' => [
            [
                'data' => $values,
                'backgroundColor' => ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56', '#F44336']
            ]
        ]`